# When I call exec over network and it last for a few moments, it fails

Tags: java, batch-file, process, mysql

I have an application developed in java and MySQL. I use it over a LAN and have hosted the application on a PC with windows 7 professional x64. This PC serves as server, and is not used for any other purposes. I have shared the folder that the application class files resides publically and other PCs can connect to this application using following batch script:

```
net use v: \\192.168.0.44\MyAppName
v:
start "" /b javaw -cp .;v:\bin;v:\lib\swt.jar;v:\lib\mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar;v:\lib\jdatepicker-1.3.2.jar;v:\lib\commons-io-2.4.jar;v:\lib\jfreechart-1.0.17.jar;v:\lib\jcommon-1.0.21.jar;v:\lib\forms-1.3.0.jar;v:\lib\activation-1.1.jar;v:\lib\commons-email-1.3.2.jar;v:\lib\mail.jar main.Main
```

All PCs are using JAVA 7 and are running windows 7, 8 and Mac, all 64 bit. Network cables are mega.

All parts of this application work fine, only the backup makes problem. I have used the following java code for that:

```
public static boolean getDatabaseBackUp() {
    boolean isSucess = false;
    File dbBackUpFile = new File("db.sql");

    File mysqlDir = new File("\\\\192.168.0.44\\xampp\\mysql");
    File mysqlBinDir = new File(mysqlDir, "bin");
    File mysqlumpFile = new File(mysqlBinDir, "mysqldump.exe");
    String dbUser = "myUserName";
    String dbPass = "myPassword";
    String dbName = "myDbName";
    String executeCmd = "";
    executeCmd = mysqlumpFile + " " + dbName + " -u " + dbUser
            + " --password=" + dbPass + " " + " -r \""
            + dbBackUpFile.getAbsolutePath() + "\"";
    System.out.println(executeCmd);
    try {
        Process runtimeProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(executeCmd);
        int processComplete = runtimeProcess.waitFor();
        if (processComplete == 0) {
            System.out.println("Process is completed");
            isSucess = true;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Process is NOT completed");
            isSucess = false;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        isSucess = false;
    }
    return isSucess;
} // getDatabaseBackUp ()
```

<del>The above code used to work fine from **all the PCs over network**, including the server, when the database was *small*, I mean around 3 MB, but *now it has grwon to 335 MB* and</del>  backup **works only when you open the application on the server PC**, when it is opened from any other PCs over the network, `getDatabaseBackUp()` returns `false`.

If I run it with `-debug -verbose` the output is:

```
\\192.168.0.44\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqldump.exe myApplication -u myUserName --password=myPassword  -r "\\192.168.0.44\myApplication\assets\db_backups\2014_06_10_16_28_13.sql"
[Loaded java.lang.ProcessBuilder from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.lang.Process from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.lang.ProcessImpl from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.lang.ProcessImpl$2 from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.jar]
Process is NOT completed
```

If I run `mysqldump ... --verobse ...` on the **server** I get:

```
C:\Users\myPcUserName>\\192.168.0.44\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqldump.exe myApplicationName -u myUserName --password=myPassword  --verbose  -r "\\192.168.0.44\myApplicationName\assets\db_backups\2014_06_11_09_59_56.sql

-- Connecting to localhost...
-- Retrieving table structure for table batch_fault_count...
-- Sending SELECT query...
-- Retrieving rows...
-- Retrieving table structure for table batch_insert_time_check...
-- It's a view, create dummy table for view
-- Retrieving table structure for table batch_status_logs...
-- Sending SELECT query...
-- Retrieving rows...
-- Retrieving table structure for table batch_types...
-- Sending SELECT query...
-- Retrieving rows...
-- Retrieving table structure for table batch_username_for_pq_check...
-- It's a view, create dummy table for view
-- Retrieving table structure for table batches...
-- Sending SELECT query...
-- Retrieving rows...
-- Retrieving table structure for table batches_price_list...
-- Sending SELECT query...
-- Retrieving rows...
-- Retrieving table structure for table dblock...
-- Sending SELECT query...
-- Retrieving rows...
-- Retrieving table structure for table digitally_verified_file_count...
-- Sending SELECT query...
-- Retrieving rows...
-- Retrieving table structure for table dvds...
-- Sending SELECT query...
-- Retrieving rows...
-- Retrieving table structure for table dvds_batches...
-- Sending SELECT query...
-- Retrieving rows...
-- Retrieving table structure for table expense_types...
-- Sending SELECT query...
-- Retrieving rows...
-- Retrieving table structure for table expenses...
-- Sending SELECT query...
-- Retrieving rows...
-- Retrieving table structure for table files...
-- Sending SELECT query...
-- Retrieving rows...
-- Retrieving table structure for table keys_values...
-- Sending SELECT query...
-- Retrieving rows...
-- Retrieving table structure for table mailing_list...
-- Sending SELECT query...
-- Retrieving rows...
-- Retrieving table structure for table qc_dblock...
-- Sending SELECT query...
-- Retrieving rows...
-- Retrieving table structure for table scanners_dirs...
-- Sending SELECT query...
-- Retrieving rows...
-- Retrieving table structure for table settings...
-- Sending SELECT query...
-- Retrieving rows...
-- Retrieving table structure for table user_check_ins...
-- Sending SELECT query...
-- Retrieving rows...
-- Retrieving table structure for table user_groups...
-- Sending SELECT query...
-- Retrieving rows...
-- Retrieving table structure for table users...
-- Sending SELECT query...
-- Retrieving rows...
-- Retrieving table structure for table users_salary...
-- Sending SELECT query...
-- Retrieving rows...
-- Retrieving view structure for table batch_fault_count...
-- It's base table, skipped
-- Retrieving view structure for table batch_insert_time_check...
-- Retrieving view structure for table batch_status_logs...
-- It's base table, skipped
-- Retrieving view structure for table batch_types...
-- It's base table, skipped
-- Retrieving view structure for table batch_username_for_pq_check...
-- Retrieving view structure for table batches...
-- It's base table, skipped
-- Retrieving view structure for table batches_price_list...
-- It's base table, skipped
-- Retrieving view structure for table dblock...
-- It's base table, skipped
-- Retrieving view structure for table digitally_verified_file_count...
-- It's base table, skipped
-- Retrieving view structure for table dvds...
-- It's base table, skipped
-- Retrieving view structure for table dvds_batches...
-- It's base table, skipped
-- Retrieving view structure for table expense_types...
-- It's base table, skipped
-- Retrieving view structure for table expenses...
-- It's base table, skipped
-- Retrieving view structure for table files...
-- It's base table, skipped
-- Retrieving view structure for table keys_values...
-- It's base table, skipped
-- Retrieving view structure for table mailing_list...
-- It's base table, skipped
-- Retrieving view structure for table qc_dblock...
-- It's base table, skipped
-- Retrieving view structure for table scanners_dirs...
-- It's base table, skipped
-- Retrieving view structure for table settings...
-- It's base table, skipped
-- Retrieving view structure for table user_check_ins...
-- It's base table, skipped
-- Retrieving view structure for table user_groups...
-- It's base table, skipped
-- Retrieving view structure for table users...
-- It's base table, skipped
-- Retrieving view structure for table users_salary...
-- It's base table, skipped
-- Disconnecting from localhost...

C:\Users\myPcUserName>
```

However If I run `mysqldump ... --verobse ...` on the **other PCs** I get:

```
C:\Users\myPcUserName>\\192.168.0.44\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqldump.exe myApplicationName -u myUserName --password=myPassword  --verbose  -r "\\192.168.0.44\myApplicationName\assets\db_backups\2014_06_11_09_59_56.sql
-- Connecting to localhost...
mysqldump: Got error: 1049: Unknown database 'myApplicationName' when selecting the database
```

can anyone tell me what is the issue and how probably I can fix it?

Comment: Your code is printing the command it will execute. What happens if you execute this command directly from command line?

Comment: @MCND that does the same thing. Since the users of this application do not have even good understanding of even the basics of computer, I have made these scripts, so that they can do what they want only by double clicking on a bat file.

Comment: It is not the same thing returning false from a function that executing a command and seeing if there is any error and what the error is. There is no output? Can you include `--verbose --debug` switches?

Comment: @MCND I added the `-verbose -debug` parameters related output to the question.

Comment: No, the arguments are to mysqldump.exe, not your application. From command line run `\\192.168.0.44\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqldump.exe myApplication -u myUserName --password=myPassword --verbose --debug -r "\\192.168.0.44\myApplication\assets\db_backups\2014_06_10_16_28_13.sql"` (with the adecuated values, of course)

Comment: @MCND I added the `--verbose` of mysql. It says the database does not exist, but the same script works on the server, and on the other PCs previously. Now I am getting doubtful if the problem is really with the size of the SQL file.

Comment: `--host=serveraddress --port=serverport` by default, mysqldump tries to connect to localhost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem comes out to be the host. I did not specify the host in the java code that used to generate the cmd command. I needed to have `-h 192.168.0.44` in cmd command, so the java code snippet should look like:

```
File dbBackUpFile = new File("db.sql");

File mysqlDir = new File("\\\\192.168.0.44\\xampp\\mysql");
File mysqlBinDir = new File(mysqlDir, "bin");
File mysqlumpFile = new File(mysqlBinDir, "mysqldump.exe");
String dbUser = "myUserName";
String dbPass = "myPassword";
String dbName = "myDbName";
String dbIp = "192.168.0.44";
    String executeCmd = "";
    executeCmd = mysqlumpFile + " " + dbName + " -u " + dbUser + " -h " + dbIp
            + " --password=" + dbPass + " " + "  -r \""
            + dbBackUpFile.getAbsolutePath() + "\"";
```